# Test nested methods in react using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

for example we have a component like

```
 const handleOnChange = address => {
        setIsDelivery(false)
        const data = {
         ...deliveryLocation,
        address: address
        };
      setDeliveryLocation(data);
 };
```

how to write test for this if it in component that i want to test

[image]
[image]

red: not tested
green: pass test

Comment: Please include your component.

Comment: there are a lot of code that not necessary for this the main thing is that   handleOnChange is in Verification component

Comment: when `handleOnChange` is triggering? where is that information?

Comment: as you can see it setState data

Comment: Can you provide the complete component code?